# Google Sheets sorting correctly then incorrectly after a few seconds

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working on the following spreadsheet that takes the results of a set of quizzes and then converts it to a league table.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HLB6KPhaE_ozT0rB53D9i1QqITUAS3Qt2uXmUpznyZk/edit?usp=sharing

This all works correctly, however I would like to sort the League Table by the number of points, when I do this it works correctly at first, but then sheets continues processing and after a couple of seconds the sorting breaks. I think it may have something to do with the array functions I'm using, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Use `query()`, like this:

`=query('Quiz League'!A1:E, "where A is not null order by E desc", 1)`

You can use `query()` to build other kinds of mini reports as well, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { 
      'Quiz Results'!A1:B, 'Quiz Results'!C1:C, iferror('Quiz Results'!A1:A/0, 3); 
      'Quiz Results'!A1:B, 'Quiz Results'!D1:D, iferror('Quiz Results'!A1:A/0, 2); 
      'Quiz Results'!A1:B, 'Quiz Results'!E1:E, iferror('Quiz Results'!A1:A/0, 1) 
    }, 
    "select Col3, sum(Col4) 
     where Col3 is not null 
     group by Col3 
     order by sum(Col4) desc", 
    0 
  ) 
)
```

...and:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { 
      'Quiz Results'!A1:B, 'Quiz Results'!C1:C, iferror('Quiz Results'!A1:A/0, 3); 
      'Quiz Results'!A1:B, 'Quiz Results'!D1:D, iferror('Quiz Results'!A1:A/0, 2); 
      'Quiz Results'!A1:B, 'Quiz Results'!E1:E, iferror('Quiz Results'!A1:A/0, 1) 
    }, 
    "select Col3, sum(Col4) 
     where Col3 is not null 
     group by Col3 
     pivot Col2
     order by Col3", 
    0 
  ) 
)
```